# Can implementation classes "inherit" XML comments from their implemented interfaces?

Tags: visual-studio, sandcastle, xml-documentation

Curious question.  I'm using Microsoft's Sandcastle to generate documentation from the XML comments in my C# code.  Several of my classes are implementing interfaces which already have commented methods.  I'd rather not duplicate the documentation in both the interface method and the public implemented method.  Is there some kind of tag I can use to "inherit" this documentation from the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature does not exist currently in Visual Studio.

You can get third party tools, such as GhostDoc that will help with creating XML documentation.  GhostDoc also has the option to generate documentation that was "inherited" like you are attempting to do.

Link: [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/)

Answer (score 6):

You can add `<inheritdoc/>` in the implementation.

You should have a look on the following thread:
[Ways to synchronize interface and implementation comments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824007/ways-to-synchronize-interface-and-implementation-comments-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for a solution, I built a library to post-process the XML documentation files to add support for an <inheritdoc/> tag.

More info at [www.inheritdoc.io](https://www.inheritdoc.io/) (free version available).