# Visual Studio Interface Comment inherence?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to link a comment/doc between the method signature and its implementation.

Example :

```
public interface IExample
{
     /// <summary>
     /// make ... 
     /// </summary>     
     void Something();
}

public class AClass : IExample
{
    void Something()
    {
    }
}
```

When I mouse Over the AClass Something method I want to have the summary of the interface method signature.

Comment: Um. What? I don't understand this question at all. Can you clarify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to synchronize interface and implementation comments in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824007/ways-to-synchronize-interface-and-implementation-comments-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) / [seealso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhd7ehkk.aspx) tags to reference declaration from the implementation part.

> The  tag lets you specify a link from within text. Use 
>   to indicate that text should be placed in a See Also section. Use the
>   cref Attribute to create internal hyperlinks to documentation pages
>   for code elements

```cs
interface ICommand
{
   void Execute();
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents a Concrete command, 
/// implements <see cref="ICommand" /> interface.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ConcreteCommand
{
   public void Execute()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I want but int automatic way